# How to fix React Redux and React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'dispatch'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I use `useDispatch()` Hook from React Redux on a functional component like this:

```
const Component = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userName = useSelect(state => state.user.name);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUserInformation());
  }, [userId]);

  return (
    <div>Hello {userName}</div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

How to remove this warning without removing the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps which can be useful to avoid other errors.

Answer (score 8):

To avoid that warning simply add `dispatch` to the dependency array. That will not invoke re-renders because dispatch value will not change.

```
const Component = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userName = useSelect(state => state.user.name);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUserInformation());
  }, [userId, dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>Hello {userName}</div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `dispatch` to your dependency array or make the dependency array empty.

First Case:

```
const Component = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userName = useSelect(state => state.user.name);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUserInformation());
  }, [userId, dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>Hello {userName}</div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

Second Case:

```
const Component = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userName = useSelect(state => state.user.name);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUserInformation());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Hello {userName}</div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

By adding these dependencies, your useEffect may cause re-rendering or not re-render at all. It all depends on your data and the context in which you use it.

Anyways, if you do not wish to follow both the above methods then //ts-ignore can work but I will not recommend this as this may create bugs in the long run.